# How do I import a utility in my playwright test while using typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, playwright, winston, playwright-test

I am writing a basic playwright project using typescript. I am trying to introduce a logger.ts that should handle creation of log files and logging any logger.info messages in the log file.

I tried below commands to generate the project and create playwright skeleton projects and using the `example.spec.ts`

```
npm install --save-dev playwright
npm install --save-dev @playwright/test
npm install --save-dev typescript@latest
npm init playwright@latest --force
```

When I try to import the `logger` file in `example.spec.ts`, it highlights below error in vscode.

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '...\POC\logger-example\tests\logger'playwright`

The directory structure is given below

[image]

I am providing the required code snippets, can anyone please help find a solution, where I can import custom utilities and use it in my playwright tests?

## Package.json

```
    {
    "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.40.1",
        "@types/node": "^20.10.1",
        "playwright": "^1.40.1",
        "typescript": "^5.3.2"
    },
    "scripts": {},
    "dependencies": {
        "winston": "^3.11.0"
    }
    }
```

## tests/logger.ts

```
    
    import winston from "winston";
    import * as path from "path";
    import * as fs from "fs";

    // Logger START
    const logDir = "logs";
    const logFileName = "playwright-logger-test.log";

    if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
    }
    const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
        level: "error",
        filename: path.join(logDir, logFileName),
        format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.json()
        ),
        handleExceptions: true,
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
        level: "info",
        filename: path.join(logDir, logFileName),
        format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.json()
        ),
        handleExceptions: true,
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
        level: "warn",
        filename: path.join(logDir, logFileName),
        format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.timestamp(),
            winston.format.json()
        ),
        handleExceptions: true,
        }),
    ],
    });

    export default logger;
    // Logger END
```

## tests/example.spec.ts

```
    import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
    import logger from './logger';

    test('has title', async ({ page }) => {
    logger.info(`Start "has title" test`);
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

    // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);
    logger.info(`End "has title" test`);
    });

    test('get started link', async ({ page }) => {
    logger.info(`Start "get started link" test`);

    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

    // Click the get started link.
    await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' }).click();

    // Expects page to have a heading with the name of Installation.
    await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Installation' })).toBeVisible();
    logger.info(`End "get started link" test`);
    });
```

Using node v14.15.0 and npx v7.5.4

**Update**
It is an import error
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a import error and not a path resolution error? If you change logger to just `()=>console.log()` does it work?

My gues is that this is not a playwright issue but a Node.js file path resolution issue. Node resolves relative to where node has been executed. E.g. if you run in `$ ~/dev node` then a "./" would resolve to "dev". Node needs to build absolute file paths and does it as said from the execution directory not the directory the file is in.

Comment: @oliverwebr: Yes it's not able to find the file, I have updated the question with screenshot of exact error from vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug with npx related to caching.

**Reference**: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/23387#issuecomment-1806309390

Here is how I fixed my issue.

1. Upgraded node version to 16.12.2

`nvm use 16.12.2`

2. Used below commands to regenerate the playwright example project

```
yarn add --dev playwright
yarn add --dev @playwright/test
yarn add --dev typescript@latest
yarn init playwright@latest --force
```

That's it, now it is able to import the `tests\logger.ts` and the log file is created as expected.

[image]